# How can I select the name of author for each post?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

```
// posts
+----+---------+------------------------+-----------+------------+
| id |  title  |        content         | author_id | visibility |
+----+---------+------------------------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | title1  | content1               | 3         | 1          |
| 2  | title2  | content2               | 2         | 0          |
+----+---------+------------------------+-----------+------------+

// users
+----+---------+----------+
| id |  fname  |  lname   |
+----+---------+----------+
| 1  | John    | Tersco   |
| 2  | Peter   | Brlew    |
| 3  | Jack    | Keveinc  |
+----+---------+----------+
```

I want this is **expected output:**

```
+----+---------+------------------------+--------------+
| id |  title  |        content         |   full_name  |
+----+---------+------------------------+--------------+
| 1  | title1  | content1               | Jack Keveinc |         
| 2  | title2  | content2               | Unknown      |
+----+---------+------------------------+--------------+
```

---

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) as full_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.id AND p.visibility = 1
```

As you see, all I need is defining `Unknown` when `p.visibility` equals  `0`. How can I do that?

Do I need either `CASE` or `COALESCE` or both of them?

---

**EDIT:** First of all I have to say Tim Biegeleisen's answer is great and all fine. Just in reality, there is one other column which I need to treat with it exactly like above. But it doesn't have `CONCAT` function. For example:

```
// users
+----+---------+----------+------------+
| id |  fname  |  lname   | reputation |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
| 1  | John    | Tersco   | 943        |
| 2  | Peter   | Brlew    | 2300       |
| 3  | Jack    | Keveinc  | 84         |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
```

And this is **expected result:**

```
+----+---------+------------------------+--------------+------------+
| id |  title  |        content         |   full_name  | reputation |
+----+---------+------------------------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | title1  | content1               | Jack Keveinc | 84         |
| 2  | title2  | content2               | Unknown      | N          |
+----+---------+------------------------+--------------+------------+
```

Ok, All I want to know: Still can I use `COALESCE` for `reputation` column? *(it doesn't have `CONCAT`)*

```
SELECT  COALESECE(reputation, 'N') reputation, ....
```

Is it fine? Or because it doesn't have `CONCAT` then I have to use `CASE` for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the query below is the best approach, because it will display `Unknown` for the `full_name` if *either* of the following conditions be true:

- a post has zero visibility (`visibility = 0`)
- a post has visibility but cannot be matched to an actual user author

Using the same join condition you originally had, in either of these cases the first and last name of the joined `users` table would be `NULL`, and we can display `Unknown`.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title,
       p.content,
       COALESECE(CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname), 'Unknown') AS full_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON p.author_id = u.id AND
       p.visibility = 1
```

**Update:**

Just using `COALESCE` on the concatenated first and last name is sufficient, because `CONCAT` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL` (q.v. the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)).

**Edit:**

If your `users` table had another column called `reputation`, then you could also use `COALESCE(u.reputation, 'N')`.  The reason for this is that *all* columns from the `users` table will be `NULL` for a record from `posts` which does not match.

Comment: Best answer, It's best to have `p.visibility = 1` in the join itself so you don't include all the rows with `p.visibility = 0`

Comment: What happens if I remove that CASE ? I guess it is redundannt. I mean using COALESCE is enough, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Case do the Job:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, case p.visibility when 0 then  'unknown' else CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) end as full_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title
     , p.content
     , CASE p.visibility
           WHEN 0 THEN 'Unknown'
           ELSE CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname)
       END AS full_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.id AND p.visibility = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname)` by `CASE WHEN u.id IS NULL THEN 'unknown' ELSE CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) END`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, case p.visibility when 0 then  'Unknown' else CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) end as full_name
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Case while selecting the columns,

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content,case when p.visibility=0 then 'Unknow' 
else CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lanme) end as full_name
FROM Posts p
JOIN users u
ON p.author_id = u.id
```